# Removing query strings for a certain location

Tags: nginx, regex

I am using nginx, and I want to remove query strings on a request in such a way that:

With this code, it's not happening. I get a 404 on /store/name.

`/store/name?page=1` becomes `/store/name`

```
location ~ /store(.*) {
  if ($query_string ~ "page") {
    rewrite ^(.*) $1? permanent;
  }
}
```

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: $uri variable. This variable is equal to current URI in the request (without arguments, those are in $args.) It can differ from $request_uri which is what is sent by the browser.

Comment: Your location still matches `/store/name` thus request is still proceeded by this location, and it just tries to serve static file names `store`. Guess you don't have it.